# How to calculate the orbital character for fatbands in Quantum Espresso?

Tags: computational-physics, software, density-functional-theory

we are calculating a fatbands structure using QE pw.x. When We get the projections by weight. There are orbitals missing in the projection file. Is there a way to get contribution about outermost orbitals instead of only valence orbitals?

the electronic configuration is this one:

```
'[Xe] 6s2 6p0 5d-1'
```

and we get the contribution of those orbitals:

Valence configuration:

```
nl 
5S 
6S 
5P
```

But still we need the information of the following orbitals:

```
5d
```

the input is this one:

```
&PROJWFC
 prefix='X'
 outdir='directory'
 filproj='proj'
 lsym=.false.
/
```

the output contains the following information

```
Atomic states used for projection
 (read from pseudopotential files):

 state #   1: atom   1 (X), wfc  1 (l=0 m= 1)
 state #   2: atom   1 (X), wfc  2 (l=0 m= 1)
 state #   3: atom   1 (X), wfc  3 (l=1 m= 1)
 state #   4: atom   1 (X), wfc  3 (l=1 m= 2)
 state #   5: atom   1 (X), wfc  3 (l=1 m= 3)
 state #   6: atom   2 (X), wfc  1 (l=0 m= 1)
 state #   7: atom   2 (X), wfc  2 (l=1 m= 1)
 state #   8: atom   2 (X), wfc  2 (l=1 m= 2)
 state #   9: atom   2 (X), wfc  2 (l=1 m= 3)
 state #  10: atom   3 (X), wfc  1 (l=0 m= 1)
 state #  11: atom   3 (X), wfc  2 (l=1 m= 1)
 state #  12: atom   3 (X), wfc  2 (l=1 m= 2)
 state #  13: atom   3 (X), wfc  2 (l=1 m= 3)
 state #  14: atom   3 (X), wfc  3 (l=2 m= 1)
 state #  15: atom   3 (X), wfc  3 (l=2 m= 2)
 state #  16: atom   3 (X), wfc  3 (l=2 m= 3)
 state #  17: atom   3 (X), wfc  3 (l=2 m= 4)
 state #  18: atom   3 (X), wfc  3 (l=2 m= 5)
```

where x indicates the element, but it doesn't show l=2. How can we get it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions about specific software tend to be considered off-topic here as there are generally better venues for these questions. In this case, there is the [Quantum Espresso Users Forum](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/users-forum/) (along with Tutorials and Documentation pages).

Comment: @KyleKanos Why not tell them about Matter Modeling Stack Exchange? [Quantum ESPRESSO is the 4th most popular tag (out of more than 400 tags) there](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/tags).